# How to use a set and queue inside a concurrent method to verify jobs that have already been done so not to queue them again?

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

This is a webcrawler to find broken links. It uses a queue to queue up links that it finds, and it uses a set so it doesn't revisit old links. 
It works fine single threaded, but not when I try to threadpool it.
Can you help me on this?

It intends to add new tuples (link,link_parent) to the queue, unless that link already exists in a set. It adds all links it parses to that set.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import queue
import concurrent.futures
import time

def iter_q(q):
  while not q.empty():
    yield q.get()

def do_stuff(curr_website_tuple,already_checked,q):
  curr_website_father = curr_website_tuple[1]
  curr_website = curr_website_tuple[0]
  already_checked.add(curr_website)
  try:
    r = requests.get(curr_website, timeout=10)
    ret_status_code = r.status_code
    if r.status_code is 200:
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
      for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if (link['href'].startswith("http") and
        "yahoo." in link['href'] and
        ".blogs.yahoo." not in link['href'] and
        "doubleclick." not in link['href'] and
        "adw.yahoo.com" not in link['href'] and
        "google." not in link['href'] and
        link['href'] not in already_checked):
          q.put((link['href'],curr_website))
      return curr_website + ' ' + curr_website_father + ' ' + str(r.status_code) + ' ' + "|Number checked:" + str(len(already_checked)) + ' ' + "|Queue size:" + str(q.qsize())
    else:
      return "Request_Error: " + ',' + curr_website + ',' + curr_website_father + ',' + str(r.status_code) + '\n'
  except Exception as e:
    return "Error: "  + ',' + curr_website + ',' + curr_website_father + ',' + str(e) + '\n'

def with_threads():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        q = queue.LifoQueue()
        already_checked = set()
        q.put(("http://www.yahoo.com",''))
        q.put(("http://news.yahoo.com",''))
        futures_dict = { executor.submit(do_stuff, qe, already_checked, q) : qe for qe in iter_q(q)}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_dict):
          print(future.result())


with_threads()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue might be that you're declaring already_checked inside the *with executor* construct. try declaring it outside and see how it goes.

Comment: doesn't seem like it :)